# 'this' keyword, not clear

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

I get confused about '**this**' keyword in the following codes, there are two 'this':

```
var Foo = function(string){
  this.name=string // 1st-this
}

Foo.prototype.get_name = function(){
  return this.name // 2nd-this
}

var myFoo = new Foo('John')

the_name=myFoo.get_name()
```

'**the_name**' is equal to 'John', the prototype method get the name by return **this.name**. But can anyone explain to me the 1st-**this** and 2nd-**this**, what do they stand for?

Comment: See [how does the `this` keyword work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Javascript, the value of `this` is dependent on **the way you call the function**.

There are 5 ways to call a function in JS, and they all have effect on `this`:

1. `new Foo();` <= here, you’re creating a new object, and `this` will reflect that new object
2. `Foo();` <= here, you're calling the function as-is, and `this` will be the global object(!)
3. `var obj = { foo: Foo };

   obj.foo();` <= here, you're calling the function as a method of `obj`; `this` will be `obj`
4. `Foo.call(thisObject, arg1, arg2);` <= here, you can specify the value of `this` in the first argument
5. `Foo.apply(thisObject, [args]);` <= here, you can specify the value of `this` in the first argument

In 4 and 5, the difference between [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) is that with `call`, you need to pass all the arguments separately, whereas with `apply`, you can pass an array containing all the arguments.

Note that in my example 2 above, the function *should* have been called `foo` instead of `Foo`. Since it’s impossible to know off-hand whether a function is supposed to be called with `new` or not, the consensus is to start the function name with a capital letter if it’s a constructor (and should be used with `new`); otherwise, it should start with lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

this link make you understand : [The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

```
function doSomething() {
   this.style.color = '#cc0000';
}
```

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element it belongs to.

Comment: Imo is that the term "owner" is misleading. E.g. a function can be a property of more than just *one* object. But of course it cannot refer to both objects at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "it depends", since  the meaning of `this` depends on the *context* in which it is invoked.

For example in things like callbacks, `this` no longer refers to the current object, but more typically to the DOM element on which the event occurred:

So this identical-looking function:

```
Foo.prototype.handleSomeEvent = function(e) {
    return this.name;
}
```

if used as an event callback would try to resolve the `name` attribute of the element, and not your object's name.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `new` keyword `this` is the instance object that you are creating.

```
var foo = new Bar();
```

i.e. the instance of `Bar` being assigned to `foo`

---

When you don't, `this` is the object on which the method you are calling lives.

```
var baz = foo.thing();
var boz = thing();
```

i.e. `foo` in the first example and `window` in the second (`window` is the default object).

---

You can also fritz with it using `apply`

```
var baz = foo.thing.apply(bar);
```

Here `this` (still inside the `thing` method) is `bar`)

Comment: @Mellon: Bonus question for you (to see whether you really understood it ;)): What does `this` refer to in `get()`? `var get = myFoo.get_name; var name = get();` (`get_name` is the function you defined in your example).

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the object invoking the function, which in this case is `myFoo`.  When you construct `myFoo` as a `new Foo('John')` the `this` keyword enables you to set `myFoo.name = 'John'`, so when you call `myFoo.get_name()` it will also let you `return myFoo.name` which equals `John`.

Comment: Thank you :), I more question, can I understand in the way that, prototype is the parent of myFoo (myFoo is the child of prototype)?

Comment: The prototype contains properties and methods that all objects created with `new Foo()` share.  So even though in `myFoo` you may override `get_name` with a function with the same name in that instance, another object `myOtherFoo` will keep `get_name` in its prototypal form.

Answer (score 1):

In your example they are the same, when you call `this` from a method you override in the prototype chain you are referring to the same thing as when calling `this` from within the constructor function.

It gets trickier when working with callbacks or when defining member variables in prototype methods.

Comment: Thank you :), I more question, can I understand in the way that, prototype is the parent of myFoo (myFoo is the child of prototype)?

Answer (score 1):

wow all of these different answers, and only one of them even used the word "context"!  Here is the straightforward answer to your question:

the `this` keyword is an object reference that points to the context object.

In your example, `this` refers to an instance of the `Foo` object.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" keyword always refers to the owner of the function. So for instance if you click on a button that accesses that function, this refers to that button. So if you have button A that has an onclick that calls that function then this is A.

In this case this would be John since in both cases they reference myFoo which is John since Myfoo is used in calling them