# What is the "this" pointer for global functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, member-functions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   ['this' keyword, not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429739/this-keyword-not-clear)
>   [this operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript)

```
function foo()
{
    if(this === window)
        return null;

    return 1;
}

var i = foo(); // returns 1;
```

What is the `this` member of a global function, and how can I test from within a function if it's being called in a global scope or as a member function?

Edit: It seems JQuery makes a difference here, since everybody assures me `foo` should return `null` for run-of-the-mill JavaScript. How does JQuery change this?

Note that the OP says, in a comment, below, that this is in a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: For a start, it's not a "member" of anything.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320677/this-operator-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Global_object) the difference is because of greasemonkey (not JQuery).

> A Greasemonkey user script, however, by default wraps up all code inside an anonymous function wrapper that swallows identifiers, causing them not to end up on the global object.

It goes on to say that you can use `@unwrap` to make `this` point to the `window` as it does with regular on-page Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the window object in this case.

Just do `alert(this);` and it will say `[object Window]`

But if you do

```
var i = new foo(); // returns an object (instance of foo);
```

then `this` refers to the instance of `foo`.

Comment: So could you say `if (this == window) ...`?

Comment: `if (this === window)` will work .. but it will always be true for those..

Comment: I've tried this (in Firefox 4), and I get the error "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 2 [nsIPromptService.alert]"

Comment: @robot, Is this for firefox plugin ?

Comment: `this` refers to the global object, which may *or may not* be `window`, depending on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

The this member refers to the entire page, and will always be defined - your foo() method will never return null.

Answer (score -1):

`this` always points on the current element. In the case of `foo()`, `this` points to `window`.

Comment: (I've edited your answer to make it clearer. "This" and "window" are words in English, as well as important terms in Javascript.)

Comment: Testing `this == foo` returns false.

Comment: Oops; testing `this == window` returns false.