# why this in javascript printing window object?

Tags: javascript

In the `console` tab of chrome developer tools, I typed `this`, and it has shown `Window` object. How `this` becomes window object here?

```js
console.log(this);
```

Consider below snippet

```js
var firstname = "Javascript";
var lastname = "Lover - SKT";

function getName() {
  this.firstname = "Sivakumar";
  this.lastname = "Tadisetti";
}

console.log(firstname);
getName();
console.log(this.lastname); // How this.lastname is working here?
```

I've read the following StackOverflow answers

[what does this mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

[this in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950564/this-in-javascript)

But didn't understand how the above snippet is working (The line I commented)

**Update:**

I have tried above code snippet in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7cyz2pn/15/) where it outputs `this.firstname` is undefined. So that's the reason I am asking this question. But in the stackoverflow code snippet it is working fine

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy it does, at least for me

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What makes you think it shouldn't work?

Comment: What do you not understand here? `this` is the `window`, and after calling `getNames()`, you are changing `window.firstname` and `window.lastname`. so in the second log, they are modified

Comment: the global scope is the window object. All global variables belong to the window object.`lastname` is declared as global variable and it can be used as `window.lastname`

Comment: Not OP, but I think the confusion is in why `firstname` *isn't* "Sivakumar".  Looks like a misunderstanding of the difference between globally scoped local variables and window object properties.  Both of these are accessible in the same way, so I can see why OP might be confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript this refers to window instead of object inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831509/javascript-this-refers-to-window-instead-of-object-inside-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy A girl has no profile picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your function, `this` is the same as window (or whatever the global context is in your runtime).  If it was a `Class method`, `this` would be the `Class instance`.

You can change `this` by using `bind`, or specifying it using `apply` and `call`.

## Global Function Example

```js
var that = {}

function getTest() {
  console.log(this === window ? "this is window" : "this is not window") 
}

getTest()
getTest.call(that)
getTest.apply(that)
getTest.bind(that)()
```

## Lambda Example

If you use lambda syntax, `this` is bound to `this` at time of calling and cannot be changed.

```js
let that = {}

let fn = () => {
  console.log(this === window ? "this is window" : "this is not window")
}

// this is always window.  You CANNOT this on a lambda.
fn()
fn.call(that)
fn.apply(that)
fn.bind(that)()
```

## Class Example

```js
class Foo {
  fn() {
    console.log(this === window ? "this is window" : "this is not window")
  }
  
  // Static methods do not have a `this`, but it can be defined by call and apply, but not bind.
  static fnStatic() {
      console.log(this === window ? "this is window" : "this is not window")
  }
}

// this is Class instance, NOT window
new Foo().fn()
// Change this from class instance to window
new Foo().fn.call(window)
new Foo().fn.apply(window)
new Foo().fn.bind(window)()

// this is undefined in a static method, unless you apply or call.  YOU CANNOT BIND a static method
Foo.fnStatic()
Foo.fnStatic.call(window)
Foo.fnStatic.apply(window)
// YOU CANNOT BIND 
Foo.fnStatic.bind()(window)
```

Answer (score 2):

In global scope, `this` is actually points to `window` object. By invoking `getName` you are doing the same as if:

```
window.firstname = "Sivakumar";
window.lastname = "Tadisetti";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object whether in strict mode or not.

and `console.log(this.lastname);` is in global scope so here `this` refers to window object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called.

In your case, commented this is called by the JavaScript's execution context, the context that called your program to be executed. Inside that context variable lastname lives and this means that it is a part of this object. You are calling it after your getTest function that changed the value of lastname variable and that is why you see in in console.log() with it's changed value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a global context then `this` refers to the `window object`.

```js
console.log(this);
```

`this` can refer to the window object in a function if the context stays the same

```js
const funcArrow = () => {console.log(this)}
const func = function(){console.log(this)};
//this has no difference
const func2 = function(){console.log(this)}.bind(this);
funcArrow(); func();
```

The context changes if you create an instance.

```js
var Car = function(){
  this.name = "bmw";
  console.log(this);
};

class Person {
  constructor(){
    this.name = "john";
    console.log(this);
  }
}

new Car(); new Person();
```

To keep the window context in an instance bind it.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(){
    this.name = "john";
  }
  
  logWindow(){
    const someFunc = function(){console.log(this)}.bind(window);
    someFunc();
  };
}

(new Person()).logWindow();
```