# Javascript apply function is not working on Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am using the following code,

```
var iphoneUrl = 'myScheme://{0}?{1}'
function callNativeFunction(functionName) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (window.andriod) {
        andriod[functionName].apply(this, args);
    }
    else {
        var params = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
            params += 'param' + (i + 1) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[i]) + '&';
        }
        params = params.slice(0, -1);// remove last &
        window.location = iphoneUrl.format(functionName, params);
    }
}
callNativeFunction('functionName', 'param1');
```

Here is String.Format,

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
          ? args[number]
          : match
        ;
    });
};
```

which great but on andriod webview apply is not working. `alert(andriod[functionName])` give me   `'function myFunc(..){[native Code]}'`. But `andriod[functionName]` does not call the function. Not If use `andriod.myFunc` then it works but I don't want the function to be hard coded.

Comment: not entirely sure, but this may be a typo. you spell android andriod several times.

Comment: Is the `apply` method perhaps overridden?  What does `alert(andriod[functionName].apply)` say?

Comment: @njzk2, I am able to call this function using andriod.myFunc. But not with andriod['myFunc'].apply

Comment: @user960567: It doesn’t what?!?  I repeat my question: *What does `alert(andriod[functionName].apply)` say?*

Comment: @Martijn, alert(andriod[functionName]) says, 'function myFunc(..){[native Code]}'

Comment: @Martijn, importantly alert(andriod[functionName].apply) says, 'function apply(..){[native Code]}'. But alert(andriod[functionName].apply(args)) does not prompt and the native function does not execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re passing `this` along as first argument to apply, but since [the value of `this` is dependent on the way you call the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429739/this-keyword-not-clear/5429817#5429817), it will merely reflect the global object, whereas it should reflect the `andriod` (sic) object.

Just replacing `this` in the following line by `andriod` should work:

```
andriod[functionName].apply(this, args);
```

into

```
andriod[functionName].apply(andriod, args);
```

Correcting `andriod` into `android` gives the following function:

```
var iphoneUrl = 'myScheme://{0}?{1}'
function callNativeFunction(functionName) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if ('android' in window) {
        window.android[functionName].apply(window.android, args);
    }
    else {
        var params = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
            params += 'param' + (i + 1) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[i]) + '&';
        }
        params = params.slice(0, -1);// remove last &
        window.location = iphoneUrl.format(functionName, params);
    }
}
callNativeFunction('functionName', 'param1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this as a work around, Not good but works,

```
function apply(obj, methodName, args) {
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0: return obj[methodName]();
        case 1: return obj[methodName](args[0]);
        case 2: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1]);
        case 3: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        case 4: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
        case 5: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
        case 6: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
        case 7: return obj[methodName](args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6]);
    }
}


function callNativeFunction(functionName) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (window.android) {
        apply(android, functionName, args);
    }
    else {
        var params = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
            params += 'param' + (i + 1) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[i]) + '&';
        }
        params = params.slice(0, -1);// remove last &
        window.location = iphoneUrl.format(functionName, params);
    }
}
```