# Can functions passed into constructors have access to the constructor's other properties?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

Typically, calling `this` would work; but I am calling the method in another context, so `this` refers to that context rather than the 'parent' object.

Here's the code:

```
var someConfig = {
  things: [
    {
      attr1: 'foo',
      attr2: 'bar',
      action: function() {
        console.log(this);
      }
    }
  ]
}

function Constructor(config) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = 'test';
  self.things = config.things;

  $.each(self.things, function(i, thing) {
    thing.action();
  });
    }

var obj = new Constructor(someConfig);
console.log(obj);
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QvMZK/3/). The goal is to have both objects that are in the console to be the same, but `this` in the context of the `action` method returns the original object to which `action` belongs, rather than the constructor.

The only thing I can think of is to pass `self` into `action`, but I think there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to tack the 'constructor' onto the config `thing` before calling the `action`.

Check out [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vor0nwe/QvMZK/4/), which was forked off yours.
I've changed two things:

First, the `action` function no longer references `this`, but rather the property `parent` of `this`.

```
  action: function() {
    console.log(this.parent);
//                  ^^^^^^^
  }
```

Second, each `thing` object receives a `parent` property, which references `self`.

```
  $.each(self.things, function(i, thing) {
    thing.parent = self;
    thing.action();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense to me. I'm a newbie to OOP, so I guess my question is, is this bad design on my part, or just a javascript peculiarity? I would typically expect an object's methods to have access to all of the object's data. Should I be extending here?

Comment: Well... Considering that (in Javascript) a single function could be a property tacked onto several different objects _at the same time_, which object's data should it refer to?

Comment: In this case, I think I’d copy the members of `things` directly onto `self`, so that you can simply use `this` in the functions. Extending would be a better way to go here (put them on `Constructor`'s `prototype`).

Comment: How do you copy onto self? That's what I'm trying to do here: `self.action = config.action;`.

Comment: If you use `self.action = config.action`, then it’ll work with just `this`.  However, you assigned `action` to a _different_ object than `self`, which is why I had to use that workaround in my answer.  (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429739/this-keyword-not-clear/5429817#5429817) for a little explanation of the *this* keyword).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a couple of points about your code. your config property is `uniqueAction` yet later you refer to it as `config.action`. When you call `obj.action` you need to call it as a function like: `obj.action();`

With that in mind, the following seems to do what you require...

```
var config = {
  action: function() {
    console.log(this.name);//<- IMPORTANT PART
  }
}

function Constructor(config) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = 'test';
  self.action = config.action;
}

var obj = new Constructor(config)
obj.action();
```

Notice that the `console.log` call now uses `this.name` instead of `self.name`.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/hRk6N/)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I fixed my code. Also, I wasn't specific enough. `this` doesn't work because I'm calling the function in another context. I also updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: @SamSelikoff: Please create a [http://jsfiddle.net/](JSFiddle) that demonstrates it not working

Comment: @SamSelikoff: In your case, `this` actually _does_ work. When you call `obj.action()`, `this` will reflect `obj`.  Which is exactly what you’re after, no?

Comment: @Martijn Sorry, I think my link was bad - I fixed it. The console shows `Object` then `Constructor`. The goal is to have the first line also be `Constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can functions passed into constructors have access to the constructor's other properties?

Yes, but only if you pass that object to the function (or implicitly use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)).

What you did try was accessing the local `self` variable from a function that was declared outside the constructor, which is just impossible.

So just use

```
{
  action: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
//              ^^^^
  }
}
```

And when calling `obj.action()` the `this` will point to the instance.