# Recursive JavaScript Method Scope

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this recursive function that is suppose to go through a JSON object to find all the subgroups.  Here is what I have:

```
var subgroupIds = [];
this.getSubGroups = function (groupId) {
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return subgroupIds;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                this.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

...where getGroups is an asynchronous function that returns all the groups.

My problem is when it gets to the recursive call, I get the error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getSubGroups'
```

I'm guessing it's a scope issue but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

As Bergi pointed out, I need to have a callback.  This is what I have now:

```
var subgroupIds = [];
var that = this;
this.getSubGroups = function (groupId,callback) {
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                callback(group.id);
                that.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The trouble now is when I call the callback, it says the function is undefined.

Ultimately, I want to return an array of sub group.id's.  I'm not sure how to get there...

Comment: How would you go detecting that `subgroupids` have been completely filled? You need some kind of callback for that.

Comment: You are right Bergi.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this` is defined at a function level, and is bound to the item in the array you're iterating over for the inner function in this case.  `this` within the inner function does not refer to the same thing as `this` within the outer function.  You can get around this by setting
`var that = this;` on the outer level and referencing `that` from within the inner function

```
var subgroupIds = [];
var that = this;
this.getSubGroups = function (groupId) {
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return subgroupIds;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                that.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

For more see [How do closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

And here for [How this works in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429739/this-keyword-not-clear?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is because thi inner function, defined in `each` does not belong to `this` instance of your class/object, isntead it refers to the callback function itself. To bypass this problem, at the object constructor, I put the folowing:

#### Solution in general:

```
function SimpleClass() {
     var _this = this;    //Private property, will be shared in all functions defined in the class
     this.value = "Hello";
     this.value2 = " world!";

     function say() {        //private function - use _this (this means something else here)
         return _this.say;   //Gets property of the object
     }
     this.say = function() { //Public function - use this
        alert(this.value+say());  //Here, we can use both this and _this
     }

}
```

#### Fix for your code:

```
var _this = this;
var subgroupIds = [];
this.getSubGroups = function (groupId) {
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return subgroupIds;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                _this.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` is not the same `this` as before. Perhaps save `this` into a variable name more relevant to the object it's referencing (I'll use `someObject`...) before your first `getSubGroups` call, and then call `someObject.getSubGroups` later.

```
var subgroupIds = [];
var someObject = this;
someObject.getSubGroups = function (groupId) {
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return subgroupIds;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                someObject.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The reason why this happens is because your function is called from the `$.each` implementation. I would refer to [MDN docs of "this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `this` refers to `$.each` callback, you can do something like this:

```
var subgroupIds = [];
var self = this;
self.getSubGroups = function (groupId) {
    self.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return subgroupIds;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
            subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                self.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```