# Recursive Asynchronous Callbacks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, closures

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122378/recursive-javascript-method-scope), I'm trying to add a callback to get the data back.  So I tried this:

```
var subgroupIds = [];
var that = this;
this.getSubGroups = function (groupId,callback) {
    var anotherObject = this;
    this.getGroups("groupId="+groupId, function(groups) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(groups)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $.each(groups, function(index,group) {
                subgroupIds.push(group.id);
                that.getSubGroups(group.id);
            });
            anotherObject.callback(group.id);
        }
     });
}
```

I thought I have a better understanding of closure after the previous question but I guess I don't...I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'callback'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

Here's the content of getGroups:

```
this.getGroups = function(filter,callback,error_callback) {
    this.getJSON('/'+apiVersion+'/groups/',function(data){
        // run through the filter engine
        output = runFilter(data, filter);
        callback(output);
    },error_callback);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `this.getGroups` should be `anotherObject.getGroups`?

Comment: Why do you use `anotherObject` instead of `that`? And why do you callback to a property, don't you want to callback to the function argument?

Comment: What is `this`/`that`? When you are declaring `this.getSubGroups`, `this` refers to `window`, so you're not doing something right to get `this` to refer to the right thing. Then, `anotherObject` just refers to the same, `window`. Also, why are you trying to use `anotherObject.callback(group.id)`? Don't you just want `callback(group.id);`?

Comment: I don't see any recursion, btw.

Comment: @beri 'that.getSubGroups(group.id);' is recursive

Comment: @Bergi I thought the same and used `that` at first but I was getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<helper> has no method 'callback'`.  As for recursion, I'm calling `that.getSubGroups(group.id)`.

Comment: could you show the body of getGroup?

Comment: @Sebas I have included the getGroups function in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be `anotherObject.callback(group.id);`, what you need is `callback(group.id);`

It looks like you're confusing `this` with `arguments` object.

`arguments` holds all parameters that are passed into the function:

```
var aFunction = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
};

aFunction(1, 2, 3, 4); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

While `this` basically refers to the "owner" of the function (which is, roughly speaking, whatever happens to be before the dot):

```
var aFunction = function () {
    console.log(this);
};

var object1 = { f: aFunction, name: "object1" };
var object2 = { f: aFunction, name: "object2" };

object1.f(); // Object { name="object1", f=function()}
object2.f(); // Object { name="object2", f=function()}
aFunction(); // Window
```

Comment: I _think_ I understand what you're saying.  I thought I was getting the error due to `callback` is an argument of `getSubGroups` and `getGroups` has not visibility to `callback` since it's another level down.  I tried changing `anotherObject.callback(group.id);` to `callback(group.id);` but I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @PLui That is because of your recursive call to `that.getSubGroups(group.id);` - you do not provide the second parameter - the callback - which is why it is `undefined`. You either have to provide a callback each time you call the function, or introduce a check: `if (callback) { callback(group.id); }`

Comment: if you want the same callback to be invoked in every recursive call, you just have to pass it along: `that.getSubGroups(group.id, callback);`

Comment: ah that got me a lot closer.  What I'm noticing now is if I have a group structure where I have a grandparent, parent and child, the recursive nature of this function will essentially call `getSubGroups` three times (for each level).  This causes `callback` to be called twice.  I really just want the last `subgroupIds` since that gives me the complete list of sub-groups.  How do I get around that?

Comment: I think my logic is flawed.  I shouldn't return an array.  Instead, perhaps I should just use `callback(group.id)` as I find the subgroups.  Thanks or the help Nikita!

Answer (score 0):

The callback is a parameter, it is not bound to the context.

I think what you want is to call the callback with `anotherObject` as the `this` value, right ?

You can achieve that with :

```
$.proxy(callback, anotherObject)(group.id);
```

Or if you only want to execute the callback, and you want to use closure, you need to add :

```
this.callback = callback; //before
var anotherObject = this;
```

Comment: With that proxy thing you mean `callback.call(anotherobject, group.id)`?